# Laravel rest api - calling SSE or Long polling blocks other HTTP request

Tags: laravel, vue.js, real-time, server-sent-events, long-polling

I'm working on a Laravel + Vue SPA with a comment module for a ticketing system (helpdesk), aiming to implement real-time comments. I've successfully implemented an SSE with a while loop. However, an issue arises when the SSE is open, and I try to make a new HTTP request — the new request seems to freeze and never completes due to the active SSE connection.

How to avoid this problem?

Than you

Able to request HTTP while SSE is open